# If $A+B=225^\circ$ then $\frac{\cot A}{1+\cot A}\cdot\frac{\cot B}{1+\cot B}=\ldots$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A+B=225^\circ$ then $\frac{\cot A}{1+\cot A}\cdot\frac{\cot B}{1+\cot B}=\ldots$

I tried using $\cot(A+B)$ formula but failed to get a proper answer.

Options are:(A) $1$; (B) $-1$; (C) $0$; (D) $\frac12$.

Comment: is this $$225^{\circ}$$?

Comment: In a multiple choice test, you can assume that there is only one solution. So here, you can just let $A=?°, B=?°$ and get the answer. Notice that you may have to expand using $\cot={\cos\over\sin}$ to avoid dividing by $0$

Comment: That aside, can you show your working in what you did to attempt to get to the answer?

Comment: @Shuri2060 For $B=135^\circ$, the expression to evaluate does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\cot{A}}{1+\cot{A}}\cdot\frac{\cot{B}}{1+\cot{B}}=\frac{\cot{A}}{1+\cot{A}}\cdot\frac{\cot\left(45^{\circ}-A\right)}{1+\cot\left(45^{\circ}-A\right)}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos{A}}{\sin{A}+\cos{A}}\cdot\frac{\cos{A}+\sin{A}}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}+\cos{A}+\sin{A}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @user466377 You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $A+B=180^\circ n+45^\circ$ for some integer $n$

$$\cot(180^\circ n+45^\circ)=\cot(A+B)$$

$$\implies\cot45^\circ=\dfrac{\cot A\cot B-1}{\cot B+\cot A}$$

$$\iff\cot B+\cot A=\cot A\cot B-1$$

$$\iff(1+\cot B)(1+\cot A)=2\cot A\cot B$$

Can you take it from here?